# Get hotel prices from Google Hotel Prices and Hotel Ads APIs

Tags: web-scraping, google-api

Recently I've discovered such thing as [Google Hotel Prices and Hotel Ads API](https://developers.google.com/hotels/hotel-prices/api-reference/v20/prices-api-v2).
If I read correctly, API is available for hotel suppliers that add their own hotels as inventory and manage prices for it. Google uses its info to provide hotel ads for particular searches.

My question is - may I (my company) as a user just consume the hotel prices info just by knowing the hotel location and name. Basically, obtain prices through API for the hotels we didn't add to Google Hotel Ads as an invenotory?

Every API that feeds prices in these API seem to request a hotel ID and hotel ID seems to be supplier-specific, and now way for a common user to get access to any hotel price. If there is, please hint me on how to. Thank you.